# Google Vision API label detection not working error: 'str' object has no attribute before request

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use the [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels) to read the labels for a image.

I am executing this on a Google Compute Engine instance with access to all Cloud APIs. And I am using a service account for authentication

I keep getting the following error
[image]

This the code I am executing

```
import io
#from google.cloud import storage
#from google.cloud.vision_v1 import ImageAnnotatorClient
from google.oauth2 import service_account
# using old version of API

from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types


image_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials='credentials.json')


with io.open('/home/username/instagram-ml/userbucket/images/test_image.jpg','rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)
#
image_response = image_client.label_detection(image =image)

labels = image_response.label_annotations
```

Up until line

```
image_response = image_client.label_detection(image =image)
```

Everything works fine and I get no authentication issues. But when I execute the above line I suddenly get this error.

Pretty much following the instructions on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels)

Not very sure what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide the client with a string (filename?) as credentials, but as specified in the [docs](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/gapic/v1/api.html), the credential argument, if passed, should be an instance of [Credentials](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials) or one of its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the error add in the following line to you code before setting the credentials:

```
print('Credendtials from environ: {}'.format(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')))
```

If the output is `Credendtials from environ: None`, then the script is not running in a context where it has the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable set.

To solve this, first ensure that you create the service account private key. Steps in creating the service account can be found in the links https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files and [Guideline on Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHkQb3gnSRA)

When you create the service account and the key, a json file will automatically download. Copy the location of this file, for eg: 'C:/awesome-credentials.json'.

Next install the following libraries:

1. pip install google-cloud-vision
2. pip install google-cloud
3. pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
4. pip install --upgrade google-auth

Then, set the credentials in the script using the following code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:/awesome-credentials.json')
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=credentials)
```

This is an example of the entire code:

```
from google.cloud import vision
import io
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def detect_text(path):
    """Detects text in the file."""
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:/awesome-credential.json')

    print('Credendtials from environ: {}'.format(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')))
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=credentials)

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print('Texts:')

    for text in texts:
        print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                    for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

        print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
```